# Delete a row from a Joined table in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Training].[UserTrainingModuleResults](
[UserTrainingModuleResultId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TrainingModules_TrainingModuleId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Users_UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[DateAndTimeStarted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[DateAndTimeCompleted] [datetime] NULL,
[NumberOfQuestionsAnswered] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[NumberOfQuestionsAnsweredCorrectly] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[TrainingModuleStatuses_TrainingModuleStatusId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_UserTrainingModuleResults] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[UserTrainingModuleResultId] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [History].[ViewTrainingModuleHistory](
[HistoryId] [int] NOT NULL,
[TrainingModules_TrainingModuleId] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ViewTrainingModuleHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[HistoryId] ASC
  )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

then i have a script that must delete from the ViewTrainingModuleHistory where TrainingModules_TrainingModuleId = UserTrainingModuleResults.TrainingModules_TrainingModuleId

```
delete from History.TrainingModuleCompletedHistory as tmch  //syntax error here
  left join Training.UserTrainingModuleResults as utmr
on utmr.UserTrainingModuleResultId = tmch.UserTrainingModuleResults_UserTrainingModuleResultId
where utmr.Users_UserId = 446 and tmch.UserTrainingModuleResults_UserTrainingModuleResultId = 110
```

the above is not correct, i get syntax error near "as" 
please help 
thanks

Comment: 154 questions asked and only 6 up votes cast.  People might start to question whether or not they should bother helping if you never reward anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete tmch  
from History.TrainingModuleCompletedHistory tmch
  left join Training.UserTrainingModuleResults utmr
on utmr.UserTrainingModuleResultId = tmch.UserTrainingModuleResults_UserTrainingModuleResultId
where utmr.Users_UserId = 446 and tmch.UserTrainingModuleResults_UserTrainingModuleResultId = 110
```

Answer (score 0):

The alias should be right after the word [`DELETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258847%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

```
delete tmch   --- < alias of table to delete records from goes here
from History.TrainingModuleCompletedHistory tmch  
left join Training.UserTrainingModuleResults utmr
  on utmr.UserTrainingModuleResultId = tmch.UserTrainingModuleResults_UserTrainingModuleResultId
where utmr.Users_UserId = 446 
  and tmch.UserTrainingModuleResults_UserTrainingModuleResultId = 110
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete tmch  
from History.TrainingModuleCompletedHistory tmch  
left join Training.UserTrainingModuleResults utmr
on utmr.UserTrainingModuleResultId = tmch.UserTrainingModuleResults_UserTrainingModuleResultId
where utmr.Users_UserId = 446 
and tmch.UserTrainingModuleResults_UserTrainingModuleResultId = 110
```